# probability convergence question

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $\{Y_{n}\}$ is a sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables and that $X_n$ = $\frac{Y_n}{n}$. Suppose that
$P(Y_1=k) = \frac{C}{k^{2}}, k=\pm 1,\pm 2,...$, where $C$ is chosen so that  $\sum_k  P(Y_1 = k) = 1$. Does $X_n \to 0$ in probability? Does $X_{n} \to 0$ with probability 1?

Approach:
Start with Chebyshev inequality $P(|X_{n} - X|> \epsilon)= P\left(\left|\frac{C}{n^3} - X\right|^{2} > ϵ^{2}\right)$. I am not sure whether this approach is right.
Throw some light please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is $X$ in your inequality?

If you want to check $X_n \to 0$, you want to see if
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \varepsilon) \to 0,
$$
that is
$$
\mathbb{P}(|Y_n| > n \varepsilon) \to 0.
$$
Neither Markov's nor Chebyshev's inequality would help here, since the $Y_n$ do not have an expectation. However, you can write it explicitly:
$$
\mathbb{P}(|Y_n| > n \varepsilon) = 2 C \sum_{k \geq n \varepsilon} \frac{1}{k^2}.
$$
Do you see why this would converge to $0$?

For a.s. convergence, it is more delicate. You want to show that for any $\omega$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n \geq N$, we have $|X_n| < \varepsilon$. In other words, it means that
$$
\mathbb{P} \left ( \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n \geq N} \{|X_n| > \epsilon \} \right ) = 1,
$$
so by taking the complement
$$
\mathbb{P} \left ( \bigcap_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{n \geq N} \{|X_n| > \epsilon \} \right ) = 0.
$$
By the second Borel-Cantelli lemma, this means that
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P} \left ( |X_n| > \epsilon \right ) < + \infty.
$$
Now, what is the behavior of
$$
\mathbb{P} \left ( |X_n| > \epsilon \right ) = \mathbb{P}(|Y_n| > n \varepsilon) = 2 C \sum_{k \geq n \varepsilon} \frac{1}{k^2}
$$
as $n \to + \infty$? This will tell you whether the series converges or not.

Answer (score 1):

$P(|X_n| >\epsilon)=P(|Y_n| >n\epsilon)=P(|Y_1| >n\epsilon)=\sum_{k >n\epsilon} \frac C {k^{2}} \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$ by convergence of $\sum \frac C {k^{2}}$. Hence $X_n \to 0$ in probability.

Now, by a similar calculation  $\sum_n P(|X_n| >1)=\sum_n \sum_{k >n} \frac C {k^{2}} =\infty$ since $\sum_{k >n} \frac C {k^{2}} \sim \frac C n$ and $\sum \frac 1 n =\infty$. Hence, by Borel - Cantelli Lemma $|X_n| >1$ infinitely often with probability $1$. Thus $X_n$ does not tend to $0$ almost surely.